# How to count records with where clause in jpa test with latest spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, where-clause, jpql

I have UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {}
```

The entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="test", name = "TBL_USERS")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User implements Persistable<String>  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", columnDefinition = "char")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NAME", columnDefinition = "char", nullable = false)
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

And in my test I want to count records with certain name like the query:

```
select count(*) from TBL_USERS where name='John';

@Test
    public void testCountSimilarNames() {
        ...
        userRepository.count() ... ?
    }
```

I use latest spring-boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something like :

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User , String >{
    Integer countByName(String name);
}
```